# Laravel - Eloquent Schema - Inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, orm

This is what my schema looks like.

### Schema:

```
User
    id
    email
    password  
    firstname  
    lastname  

Profile
    user_id (foreign key)
    name
    weight
    height
```

### Model

I have a one to many relationship for the models.

#### User

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function Profiles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Profile');
    }
```

#### Profile

```
class Profile extends Eloquent {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

### Problem

I realized that creating a separate `name` field in my `Profile` is already redundant to the `firstname` & `lastname` in `User`.

I plan to create a `Profile` property called `name` that is just referenced from the `User` model.

Any help on accomplishing this?  Would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!